# Jagged edges with simple render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, edges, gpu

I have used a basic template for rendering simple shapes against a blank background.

Load generic blender project, insert shape, change from eevee to cycles, GPU rendered.... no changes to anything else.

When I rendered any shape before the edges came up clean and smooth.... now upon doing the same setup they are extremely jagged, no smooth edges ever now, now matter what shape I insert.

See the image attached for a simple shape, rendered with jagged edges - no changes are made to teh general blender project setup apart from changing to cycles with GPU

Thanks - just confused why from one project set up like this, it was fine, and now all are jagged.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show us your blend file?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the number of samples?  This looks like you aren't using enough samples to me.

Comment: @Chris - how do I attach a blend file here on stackoverflow? Its literally an new project, blender 2.8.... add a blank mesh, cycles, GPU rendering..... thats it..... and this happens

Comment: @PGMath - render sampling is 256

Comment: with this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Chris & PGMath - the same project setup, the day previous was rendering perfect shapes, no jagged edges.... now upon doing the exact same set up, i get jagged edges

Comment: @Chris - see updated post

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your .blend-File. That helped a lot.

The problem is the lighting.

If you change your lighting settings to this:

[image]

you get this: (and yes, i added the blue cube to check, what's going on ;)

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Could you please add a little bit more explanation why it happens? Just so your answer is more useful to new users who aren't familiar with lighting. Thanks :).

Comment: Hi Jachym, if i knew it, i would ;) i just found out it is the reason. Why it is, i have no idea. But if you know, just write in the comments and i will update the answer. Sorry for my less knowledge ;(

Comment: that worked yea.... more confused now however - thanks though!